# Sort array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, object-literal

I have an array of object literals like this:

```
var myArr = [];

myArr[0] = {
   'score': 4,
   'name': 'foo'
}

myArr[1] = {
   'score': 1,
   'name': 'bar'
}

myArr[2] = {
   'score': 3,
   'name': 'foobar'
}
```

How would I sort the array so it ascends by the 'score' parameter such that it would change to:

```
myArr[0] = {
   'score': 1,
   'name': 'bar'
}

myArr[1] = {
   'score': 3,
   'name': 'foobar'
}

myArr[2] = {
   'score': 4,
   'name': 'foo'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `myArr.sort(function (a, b) {return a.score - b.score});`

The way the array elements are sorted depends on what number the function passed in returns:

- `< 0` (negative number): `a` goes ahead of `b`
- `> 0` (positive number): `b` goes ahead of `a`
- `0`: In this cases the two numbers will be adjacent in the sorted list. However, the sort is not guaranteed to be stable: the order of `a` and `b` relative to each other *may* change.

Comment: +1. And see [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for why you use `-` rather than `<`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: while you were typing your comment, I added a paragraph explaining that. Hopefully I was clear. It is a very good reference to see though!

Comment: Too much mucking about with Scheme and Haskell :(

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at the [Array.sort documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on MDN. Specifically at the documentation about providing a custom compareFunction

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myArray = [  
    {
   'score': 4,
   'name': 'foo'
},{
   'score': 1,
   'name': 'bar'
},{
   'score': 3,
   'name': 'foobar'
}
]

const myOrderedArray = _.sortBy(myArray, o => o.name);
console.log(myOrderedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

[lodash sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy)