# How do I sort this array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876424/sort-array-of-objects)

```
[ { name: 'jane', id:'3' }
  { name: 'zac', id: '5' }
  { name: 'amber', id: '2 }
]
```

How do I sort this alphabetically by name, ascending?

The result should be:

```
[ { name: 'amber', id: '2' }
  { name: 'jane', id:'3' }
  { name: 'zac', id: '5' }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You can pass it a custom function to use to compare objects. To compare strings, you can use [`String.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Put it together, and you get this:

```
var data=[
    { name: 'jane',  id: 3 }
    { name: 'zac',   id: 5 }
    { name: 'amber', id: 2 }
];
console.log("Unsorted:", data);
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
console.log("Sorted:", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[{ name: 'jane',  id:'3' },
 { name: 'zac',   id: '5'},
 { name: 'amber', id: '2'}].sort(
    function (a,b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    }
);
```

Comment: I hadn't known about `localeCompare`. Neat.