# Sort array by value from sub-array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Im trying to sort the items from an object/array by their "name" item,

I used this page for reference [Sort array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876424/sort-array-of-objects) and build the piece of code below:

```
var alphabet = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8,
    i: 9,
    j: 10,
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13,
    n: 14,
    o: 15,
    p: 16,
    q: 17,
    r: 18,
    s: 19,
    t: 20,
    u: 21,
    v: 22,
    w: 23,
    x: 24,
    y: 25,
    z: 26
}

var test = {
    item: {
        name: "Name here",
        email: "example@example.com"
    },

    item2: {
        name: "Another name",
        email: "test@test.com"
    },

    item3: {
        name: "B name",
        email: "test@example.com"
    },

    item4: {
        name: "Z name",
        email: "example@text.com"
    }
};
test.sort(function (a, b) {return alphabet[a.name.charAt(0)] - alphabet[b.name.charAt(0)]});

console.log(test);
```

Unfortunately no errors are returned and the console.log doesn't returns anything either.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
After the answer has been given, it seemed the variable "test" was required to be an array, however, the variable was generated dynamically in an external library, therefor I made this little piece of code.
If anyone has the same issue, feel free to use it.

```
var temp = [];
$.each(test, function(index, value){
    temp.push(this);
});

//temp is the resulting array
```

Comment: There is no `sort` method for Objects--only Arrays! If you want to sort the object, your best bet is probably to map the keys in test to an Array and call `sort` from there.

Comment: You are only sorting by the first letter. Multiple names with the same first letter will sort semi-randomly. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is an object, not an array. Perhaps you want this:

```
var test = [
    {
        name: "Name here",
        email: "example@example.com"
    },
    ⋮
];
```

If you need the `item`, `item1`, … to be retained against each object, you could add them as fields of each object:

```
var test = [
    {
        id: "item",
        name: "Name here",
        email: "example@example.com"
    },
    ⋮
];
```

To sort alphabetically, you need a case-insensitive comparator (and forget the `alphabet` object):

```
compareAlpha = function(a, b) {
  a = a.name.toUpperCase(); b = b.name.toUpperCase();
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: isnt the compareAlpha function doing almost the same as the current marked answer?

Comment: @xorinzor: No, it's comparing the entire string (not just the first character) and doesn't rely on an `alphabet` object.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, test should be an array, not an object.  Secondly, I think you are missing a call to .toLowerCase() after selecting the character.

```
test.sort(function (a, b) {
    return alphabet[a.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase()] - alphabet[b.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase()];
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, I indeed forgot the .toLowerCase() function, it is working perfect now!